# Twitter Type Ahead Highlight Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, bootstrap-typeahead

I have implemented the [Twitter Type Ahead](http://engineering.twitter.com/2013/02/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me.html) on my page and it looks great. But for some reason when I arrow down the list of suggestions, the items are not highlighted, but they populate the text box. However, when I hover over the drop down of suggestions with my mouse, the items are highlighted. Is there a reason why the items would not highlight when arrow'd through? If so, how can I accomplish this?

```
myTypeahead= $('#txtBox').typeahead({
            name: 'typeahead',
            valueKey: "Value",
            remote: 'serviceHander.ashx',
            template: ['<p>{{Value}}</p>'],
            engine: Hogan,
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer.

Turns out that my CSS properties were getting inherited and I had to set the `.tt-is-under-cursor` explicitly like so:

```
.tt-is-under-cursor {
    background-color: #000000!important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The class has been renamed to `.tt-cursor`

Example:

```
.tt-cursor {
    background-color: #000000!important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: The current release (0.10.5) has renamed the CSS class to just `tt-cursor`.

Answer (score 11):

Selected suggestion gets the class .tt-cursor.

```
.tt-cursor{
    color:#f1b218;
}
```